# Angular 2: component reusability. Cannot bind data

Tags: binding, components, angular, reusability

I tried to bind data in my component in order to can use select and select department for employee.
My component code looks like this:

```
  getAll(){
    if(this.searchString.length > 0){
        this._employeeService.getEmployeesBySearch(this.searchString,this.pageNumber, this.pageSize).subscribe(data => {this.bindData(data,this.departments)});
    }else{
         this._employeeService.getEmployees(this.pageNumber, this.pageSize).subscribe(data => {this.bindData(data, this.departments)});
    }
  }


   bindData(data,departments) {
            this.employees = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.employees.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < this.departments.length; j++) {
                    if (this.departments[j].departmentNo == this.employees[i].departmentNo) {
                        this.employees[i].Department = {
                            departmentNo: this.departments[j].departmentNo,
                            departmentName: this.departments[j].departmentName,
                            departmentLocation: this.departments[j].departmentLocation
                        }

                        };
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and my html table is really simple.

```
  <table align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>                   
                    <td><strong>Employee</strong></td>
                     <td><strong>Department</strong></td>   
                    <td><strong>Salary</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Edit</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#employee of employees| searchString:listFilter.value">
                    <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Department.departmentNo}}-{{employee.Department.departmentName}} </td>
                    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btnEdit" (click)="showEdit(employee)" >Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button class="btnDelete" (click)=deleteEmployee(employee)>Delete</button></td>             
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

   <br/><br/>
```

The problem is that it throws an error:

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]' in [employees| searchString:listFilter.value in EmployeeComponent@30:20].

I really don't know why it happend since in my model (from backend side I have included Department object). Without binding everything works fine, any suggestions? (in Angular 1 this approach works like a charm).

`data` looks like

```
"[ {
    "employeeNo":4,
    "departmentNo":4,
    "employeeName":"Branka Bilic",
    "salary":30000.0000,
    "lastModifyDate":"2016-02-01T00:00:00",
    "Department":{‌​       
        "departmentNo":4,
        "departmentName":"Sales",
        "departmentLocation":"Pula"
    }, etc...
}]"
```

My pipe for search by name of employee looks:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "searchString"   
})
export class SearchPipe{
    transform(value: any, args: string[]): any{
        let filter = args[0].toLocaleLowerCase();
       return filter ? value.filter(employee => employee.employeeName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems `employees` is not an array. Can you verify?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replay I got this in Chrome: {"employeeNo":4,"departmentNo":4,"employeeName":"Branka Bilic","salary":30000.0000,"lastModifyDate":"2016-02-01T00:00:00","Department":{"departmentNo":4,"departmentName":"Sales","departmentLocation":"Pula"}}. And you are right, but how can I convert employees into array?

Comment: The data looks like one employee, why do you need `ngFor`?

Comment: Actually I got an array of employees objects and inside employee object is department object.No, it is not one employee. It originally looks like this: "[{"employeeNo":4,"departmentNo":4,"employeeName":"Branka Bilic","salary":30000.0000,"lastModifyDate":"2016-02-01T00:00:00","Department":{"departmentNo":4,"departmentName":"Sales","departmentLocation":"Pula"}}, and other 10 ]"

Comment: Could be a problem with the `searchFilter` pipe. Can you please edit the question and add the code for the pipe?

Comment: Hard to tell. This simplified example works fine https://plnkr.co/edit/SYg78ARHhMbYeivuiVVa?p=preview

Comment: The pipe is added, I can't see how it can be problem. I'm very confused  with this unclear error :/ @GünterZöchbauer This pipe works fine when I don't use bindData function.

Comment: If you can modify the Plunker I linked to in my previous comment, so that it reproduces your problem it would be easier to figure out why you run into that problem.

Comment: `No idea what you mean by "this is private". You can create a copy of the Plunker using the "Fork" button.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/5q8GnyB93ek7xwgAJfBv?p=preview do you see changes? I want sth like this. :)

Comment: Yup, seems to work fine. I would need a way to reproduce you problem.

Comment: I updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5q8GnyB93ek7xwgAJfBv?p=preview. As you can see It cannot display data now.

Comment: That's because you're passing `data` here `return this.bindData(data, this.departments);` but there is no `data`.

Comment: Yes, and when I change my data into this.employees, I can see values. But, how can I do this in lambda expression in my original code: .subscribe(data => {this.bindData(data, this.departments)}), inside subscribe method? I refactor subscribe to look like this: subscribe(employees => this.bindData(this.employees, this.departments)); but then nothing happens